# FormatException: Invalid character (at character 12) in Dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, https

I am trying to build the following URI in flutter but a got an error.
the code:

```
void main() {
String APIHOST = 'hammbwdsc02/visoon-backend';
var uri = Uri.https(APIHOST, '/path', {'q': 'dart'});
print(uri); 
}
```

(this code is tested: https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true)
output:

```
Uncaught Error: FormatException: Invalid character (at character 12)
hammbwdsc02/visoon-backend
           ^
```

Does someone know why am I getting this error?

Comment: Hostnames cannot contain `/`. It seems like you have part of your PATH in the hostname?

Comment: @julemand101 yes, I do have ```/``` in my Hostname, I have a couple of projects under URL ``` https://server_name/project_name/  ```, now my question is how can fix it in flutter?

Comment: You can't. Hostnames does not contain `/`. You need to fix your hostname so it actually matches the name of your host. Again, it seems like you have some of the path as your hostname. You should split it into two different properties so you can have: `Uri.https(APIHOST, '$APIHOST_PREFIX/path', {'q': 'dart'});` . So it e.g. becomes: `Uri.https('hammbwdsc02', 'visoon-backend/path', {'q': 'dart'});`

Comment: @julemand101 thank you very much. one other question, now it works on the server how about the ```http://localhsot/``` what is the best solution that works with both http and https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by julemand101 in the comments, hostnames cannot contain the `/` character.

In your example the hostname should be `hammbwsc02` and the `visoon-backend` should be added to the path. Like so:

```dart
void main() {
  String APIHOST = 'hammbwdsc02';
  var uri = Uri.https(APIHOST, '/visoon-backend/path', {'q': 'dart'});
  print(uri); 
}
```

The structure of the URL is explained in more detail here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Comment: thank u very much, now it works on the server how about the ```http://localhsot/``` what is the best solution that works with both http and https

Comment: @Davood You could have a boolean property like `HTTPS` which tells if it should use `Uri.https` or `Uri.http` to create the URI. I would create a helper method to do this logic instead of filling your system with a lot of checks.

Comment: That really depends on the development environment and which host solution you are using (i.e. Linux with Apache, macOS or Windows with IIS). Alternatively you could use (as @julemand101 mentioned) easily switch between HTTP and HTTPS depending on the host. For example (simple version): `var uri = (APIHOST == 'localhost') ? Uri.http(APIHOST, '/visoon-backend/path, {'q', 'dart'}) : Uri.https(APIHOST, '/visoon-backend/path, {'q', 'dart'});`